# The default service() function of servlet class

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to understand the default service() of the servlet class in Java. I am reading this page: http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=47730   This says 
NOTE: the doGet() and doPost() methods (as well as other HttpServlet methods) are called by the service() method.
But I tested in a program, I let only default service() function let operate, but I observed that only doGet() gets called ?  The doPost() does not get called..
Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you tried with Post action?  provide some code which u tried.

Comment: And what is the HTTP request method? Obviously GET.

Comment: My HTTP request is <body>
   <a id=dldbtn href="http://localhost:8080/Encryption/ServletLifeCycleExample"     rel="nofollow">Click to follow</a>
</body>   ...... How can I generate a corresponding Post request to test?

Comment: A GET request retrieves data from a web server by specifying parameters in the URL portion of the request.  -- This means Get method is used to transfer data from the Server to the browser .
The POST method is used when you want to send some data to the server, for example, file update, form data, etc. .... This means that POST method will be used to transfer info from the browser to the server.

My above code looks to me browser sending info to server, so POST should be called. Strange!!

Comment: I think I got it now - GET and POST have to be coded with a method tag like the following : <form action="Login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="login">
    <span class="error">${error}</span>
</form>
Then it would be possible to have the doPost method called from the LoginServlet.java file . Its not that a URL has to be posted (like the localhost:8080... above I posted) that results in a call to doPost. Thank you Everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GET method is called in 2 cases:
1) an url request is made (you enter a webpage) - that's why if you don't have an implementation of doGet() you will receive an exception
2) a form is submited from a html/jsp and the method is set on "GET"
The Post method is called when a form is submited with method="POST"

Answer (score 1):

Following is the complete implementation for `service` method taken from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax.servlet/servlet-api/2.5/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.java#HttpServlet.service%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%2Cjavax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29)
 As can be seen from the implementation it gets the http method from request and depending upon the method appropriate implementation is called

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String method = req.getMethod();

    if (method.equals(METHOD_GET)) {
        long lastModified = getLastModified(req);
        if (lastModified == -1) {
            // servlet doesn't support if-modified-since, no reason
            // to go through further expensive logic
            doGet(req, resp);
        } else {
            long ifModifiedSince = req.getDateHeader(HEADER_IFMODSINCE);
            if (ifModifiedSince < (lastModified / 1000 * 1000)) {
                // If the servlet mod time is later, call doGet()
                // Round down to the nearest second for a proper compare
                // A ifModifiedSince of -1 will always be less
                maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
                doGet(req, resp);
            } else {
                resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_MODIFIED);
            }
        }

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_HEAD)) {
        long lastModified = getLastModified(req);
        maybeSetLastModified(resp, lastModified);
        doHead(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_POST)) {
        doPost(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_PUT)) {
        doPut(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_DELETE)) {
        doDelete(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_OPTIONS)) {
        doOptions(req, resp);

    } else if (method.equals(METHOD_TRACE)) {
        doTrace(req, resp);

    } else {
        //
        // Note that this means NO servlet supports whatever
        // method was requested, anywhere on this server.
        //

        String errMsg = lStrings.getString("http.method_not_implemented");
        Object[] errArgs = new Object[1];
        errArgs[0] = method;
        errMsg = MessageFormat.format(errMsg, errArgs);

        resp.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, errMsg);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This clears the doubt. The appropriate method gets called depending on what happens at the browser (am I correct?) [what kind of request is sent to service() : Get or Post I mean]. Its not that from service() doGet() and doPost() are as default called.

Comment: Yes this is how its implemented for servlet API. This implementation might vary for other vendors. But it will  be pretty much same.

Comment: Accept this answer if this is correct so that it helps others as well